# Echo EOT - how can i use loops and conditional operator inside it?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a question about code like as below:

```
echo <<<EOT 
          <div class="quick-view-list nav">

                  How can i use loop or conditional operator here?

                <a class="active" href="$similarProduct0">
                  <img src="$similarProductImg0" alt="Similar Product" width="100px" height="112px">
                </a>
                <a href="$similarProduct1">
                  <img src="$similarProductImg1" alt="Similar Product" width="100px" height="112px">
                </a>
                <a href="$similarProduct2">
                  <img src="$similarProductImg2" alt="Similar Product" width="100px" height="112px">
                </a>
              </div>
         EOT;
```

Is it even possible? 
Just found EOT and its fits perfectly for me - html is much longer than here.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean`? Your code can be written like this:

```
<?php // assuming php open here...


ob_start(); ?>
<div class="quick-view-list nav">
<?php
    // do your conditional operator here....
?>
<a class="active" href="<?php echo $similarProduct0; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $similarProductImg0; ?>" alt="Similar Product" width="100px" height="112px">
</a>
<a href="<?php echo $similarProduct1; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $similarProductImg1; ?>" alt="Similar Product" width="100px" height="112px">
</a>
<a href="<?php echo $similarProduct2; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $similarProductImg2; ?>" alt="Similar Product" width="100px" height="112px">
</a>
</div>
<?php 
echo ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Just tried, its not working.  Nothing display. Thanks anyway.

Comment: it should work, here's a [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/535191eaa3bf9cab9dd098035b745455792768db), in the demo you need to click "Execute code" button to see the output

Comment: It's worked. It wasn't worked because of my mistake.... Thanks!